# Change System properties for h2 database

Tags: java, h2, mainframe

I tried to run a jar file from mainframes USS.

```
java -jar Batch.jar Batch.cfg
```

I got the below h2 exception. Looks like I don't have necessary permission to write it to /test.trace.db. I would like to change the directory so that I don't need to worry about the access. How can I specify the directory for the trace file with java -jar command?

```
org.h2.message.DbException: Log file error: "/test.trace.db", cause: "java.io.FileNotFoundException: /test.trace.db (EDC5111I Permission denied.)" [90034-190]
```

Answer (score 0):

According [h2 documentation](https://www.h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/engine/SysProperties.htmlhttps://www.h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/engine/SysProperties.html), you need to update system property `h2.clientTraceDirectory`.
Something like `java -Dh2.clientTraceDirectory=mydir -jar Batch.jar Batch.cfg`